# Is it thread safe to update different properties of an object from different threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Consider the pseudo code below.  I have a class with 3 properties and each gets populated from a different methods in parallel.

Would I get into trouble populating different properties of the same class instance from separate threads? I've setup a [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gqhtYu) and it seems like it runs fine.

If this code would cause threading issues, what method should I use to lock the specific instance of the Response class while populating the properties?

```
class Response {
    public string Response1 { get; set; }
    public string Response2 { get; set; }
    public string Response3 { get; set; }
}

void foo() {
    var response = new Response();

    var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetResponse1(response));
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetResponse2(response));
    var task3 = Task.Run(() => GetResponse3(response));

    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);        
}

void GetResponse1(Response response) {
    response.Response1 = fetchSomeValue1();
}

void GetResponse2(Response response) {
    response.Response2 = fetchSomeValue2();
}

void GetResponse3(Response response) {
    response.Response3 = fetchSomeValue3();
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you expecting?

Comment: @trailmax Threading deadlocking, thread safety - things of that nature.

Comment: Task and Threads are not the same things. When you use Task it is more like the promise of a result in the future. so think in those terms

Comment: @FortyTwo In this case, Task.Run is the same as Thread.Start -  functionally they do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is only one instance of the class (held in the `response` local variable), then there is nothing to lock at the class level.  There is an implicitly captured closure over the `response` variable as it passes into those tasks, but that is just a *pointer* to the instance sitting in heap memory - not the object itself.

Since each auto-property's backing field is independent (held in a separate memory location within the class instance), and each method is updating a separate property (and thus a separate field), then you have no update conflict.  These backing fields are not interdependent.

In other words, no two tasks are trying to update the same memory location at the same time, and thus *this code* is thread safe.

*However*, if you had more than one task updating the *same* item at potentially the same time, then it would *not* be thread safe, and you'd have to implement a locking mechanism or store your data in an inherently  thread-safe object (such as a `ConcurrentDictionary`, etc.).

Comment: That's playing it loose for properties; you have no way of knowing if the call graph of two properties end up touching the same memory. It would be unsafe to change properties that are backed by a single bit field, for instance. Even with reference types, you could end up with surprises.

Comment: There is a single instance of the class in this example.  However, it runs in a web server, so there will be thousands of instances.  Still safe?

Comment: @zneak - Correct.  But in this particular case, each auto-implemented property is backed with its own field, so there's no conflict.  I'm not advocating for code like this - just saying the *code shown here* does not require locking.

Comment: Sure. Be mindful that the way the question's title is under-specific and that your answer could be found out of context in the future.

Comment: @AngryHacker - If each updating task is only updating a single instance, then there's no conflict.  If you have two tasks potentially hitting the same property on the same instance then there is.

Comment: @AngryHacker - Also, if this is representative of the code in your web server, I strongly recommend against using `Task.WaitAll`.  Instead, use `async` and `await`, along with `await Task.WhenAll` if you have multiple things to await in parallel.  Avoid `Task.Run` as well (if you can).  Instead use asynchronous APIs when you have I/O bound tasks (file access, network access, db access, etc.) and move long-running or CPU intensive tasks to a separate offline process through whatever queuing mechanism you prefer.

Comment: @MattJohnson As far as avoiding Task.Run, the code that populates the properties (e.g. fetchSomeValue1) doesn't have an async API.  Also, what exactly is the downside of WaitAll vs WhenAll (async/await)?

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` is for synchronous code.  It is blocking, just like calling `.Wait()` or `.Result` (unless the task has completed already).  It should rarely be used.  `Task.WhenAll` is for asynchronous code and is quite commonly used.

Comment: Lots of stuff on this topic here on StackOverflow already, and elsewhere on the Internet, so I won't try to restate it all in comments here.  But some of my favorites are [Stephen Cleary's MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (and lots more [on his blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/)), as well as [Lucian Wischik's Channel 9 videos](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async) (see video tips #2 and #4 especially for your scenarios).

Comment: It actually depends on a property type whether it's safe or not to update it from different threads. Assignments of references and 32-bit value types are atomic so no synchronization is needed (it's true for strings in the given example as they're references). But that's only valid if the fields have no relationship to each other from the standpoint of entire state consistency which is rare I think because if they are kept in the same class and independent to each other something is wrong with design I'd say.

Comment: @MattJohnson I guess, I am not fully groking it.  Task.WaitAll() is blocking, as you said. That is exactly what I want - block until all these tasks are completed.  Why wouldn't I want that?

Comment: With async/await, the thread is returned to the threadpool so it can be reused.  This cannot happen if you block on the thread.  There's a huge throughput benefit in a web app when you use async properly.  See also [Two Ways to Do Async/Await in ASP.NET Wrong (and How to Fix Them)](https://exceptionnotfound.net/two-ways-to-do-async-await-in-asp-net-wrong-and-how-to-fix-them/), [Understanding Async/Await In C#](http://blog.techdominator.com/article/understanding_async_await_c_sharp.html), [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), etc..

Comment: @MattJohnson I see what you mean.  Unfortunately, this is an old webforms project and I'd have to rewrite half the application to be async/await all the way.  Will have to stick with holding on to the thread for now.  Thank you for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you go this way:

```
var response = Task<Response>
                    .Factory
                    .ContinueWhenAll(new Task<string>[]{task1, task2, task3},
                                            tasks => new Response {
                                                                    Response1 = tasks[0].Result, 
                                                                    Response2 = tasks[1].Result, 
                                                                    Response3 = tasks[2].Result
                                                                    })
                    .Result;
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LHUa6G